# Looking for specifically distributed dataset for classification task

Tags: data-request

I'm working on a specific classifier which can classify the below toy data, which is a 2-class problem but the classes are distributed among each others. So it is not possible to solve it by typical SVM or Knn or prototype based classifiers.

[image]

But in order to show the practical use of my method, i need some real dataset generally similar to the above condition. It can be n-class problem, where the class data are coordinated among each others, but locally separable, and shouldn't be possible to achieve high performance using Knn or SVM classifiers.

I was wondering if such dataset is available anywhere?